# How to code distance in java android use place_id from autocompleteText

Tags: java, android

please help, i have some code to show a distance. before i use static code for get lat and long. but i need to get lat and long from user..need help how i can get this latitude and longitude from place_id /.

public void setDirectionMap()
 ArrayList list = MainActivity.arrJsonTargetLocation;

```
    JSONObject startLocation = MainActivity.jsonStartLocation;
    ArrayList targetLocation = MainActivity.arrJsonTargetLocation;


    if( list != null )

    {
        JSONObject targetLocationList = (JSONObject) list.get(list.size() - 1);
    }


        LatLng start_point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(startLocation.getString(``lat``)),
                double.parseDouble(startLocation.getString(``lng``)));

        LatLng target_point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(targetLocation.indexOf(``lat``)),
                double.parseDouble(targetLocation.indexOf(``lng``)));

        GoDelivery.geoPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


        Log.i(TAG, ``#FROM: `` + start_point.toString() + `` -- #TO : `` + target_point.toString());

        System.out.println(``=======================ORDER==================================``);
        System.out.println(``#FROM: `` + start_point.toString() + `` -- #TO : `` + target_point.toString());

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder jsonResultsDetail = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(DIRECTION_API_BASE + OUT_JSON);
            //sb.append(``&components=country:gr``);
            sb.append(``?key=`` + API_KEY);
            sb.append(``&origin=`` +
                    start_point.latitude + ``,`` +
                    start_point.longitude +
                    ``&destination=`` +
                    target_point.latitude + ``,`` +
                    target_point.longitude +
                    ``&avoid=tolls``);

            Log.i(TAG, ``Query String: `` + sb.toString());
            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
            //Log.i(TAG,``===============DIRECTIONS===============``);
            //Log.i(TAG,jsonResults.toString());


            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ``MalformedURL ``, e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ``IOException ``, e);
        } catch () {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ``Throwable``, e);
        }


    try {

       // double place_id = JSONArray.getDouble(``latitude``);
        //double place_id = JSONArray.getDouble(``longitude``);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonObj.getJSONArray(``routes``).getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray(``legs``).getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject jsonSumDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject(``distance``);
        JSONObject jsonSumDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject(``duration``);
        JSONArray  jsonSteps = jsonLeg.getJSONArray(``steps``);
        JSONObject jsonObjlat = new JSONObject().getJSONObject(``lat``);
        JSONObject jsonObjlng = new JSONObject().getJSONObject(``lng``);
```

Comment: What's the specific issue that you're encountering with your code? Could your question be restated as 'How to get the latitude and longitude of an Android device'? 

Also, there are a lot of backticks ` in your code, I assume they're meant to be double quotes "?

Comment: i just need to know . how i can get a distance from  insert location by user :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry dude , It is not that to tough
Just pass your place id and your key in this url

[This url will return json containing all the info of the place.](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/jsonhttps://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=%7Bplaceid%7D&key=%7Bkey%7D)

once you got json then you need to parse the json string to get the lat and lang .